# Save file automatically without prompting to save it in web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

In downloading any PDF Files, we need to click on save as popup window in IE and saving it into a folder.

Now, as an automation project, I want that save as popup window should be automatically clicked and it should save the files in the provided folder.

Kindly help us in C# code.

Many thanks.

Comment: Not possible. The user decides where to download a file.

Comment: You can send the file to the user automatically, but you can not choose where it will be downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can set it through code because its all about browser settings also I don't find any option in IE. However in Google Chrome you can customize your downloads using its setting. Please ask the users of your application to start using Chrome (if possible) and change its downloads setting as per the screen shot given below:

[image]